# jQuery: using localized variable

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to use jQuery Cookie in order to show/hide a div element.

```
var cExpiry = lu_ban_object.cExpiry;

jQuery('.float_close').click(function () {
                jQuery('.float_notice').fadeToggle('slow');
                jQuery.cookie('noticeVisibility', 'hidden', {
                    expires: [cExpiry], //problem is here
                    path: '/'
                });
```

The `expires:` would be a number and it represents the cookie expiry day. that number is being stored in an array and then localized, I have assigned that localized numebr to the `cExpiry` variable, however it is not accepting the brackets, `[]` I have tried `()` and `{}` but it is not working, also `+[cExpiry]+`

I get the following error;

```
Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Array] has no method 'toUTCString'
```

How do I change the data type to number? according to the screenshot it is saved as string.

[image: jquery]

Comment: Have you tried with out the brackets entirely? The expires object is expecting a value that it can parse as a date rather than an array.

Comment: the value assign to the `cExpiry` variable is not an array, is just a number ie. 5, when I call it using `alert(cExpiry);` it shows 5 which means the cookie expires in 5 days

Comment: how can I change the data type from string to number?

Comment: Placing squared brackets around it is making it an array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`expires` needs to be a Date object or a number. From your question, it looks like `cExpiry` is a number already, so no need to cast it as an Object or Array by wrapping it in brackets.

`cExpiry` might stored as a string, if that's the case then you can use parseInt to cast it as a number: `parseInt(cExpiry, 10);`

From the [documentation](https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie#expires):

> Value can be a Number which will be interpreted as days from time of
>   creation or a Date object

Comment: When I call alert(cExpiry); it shows `5`, the issue lies in the use of brackets or parenthesis or what ever I think is not properly being wrapped.

Comment: It might be a string, try using `parseInt(cExpiry, 10)` to cast it as a number

Comment: Indeed it is a string, how do I set the data type to number before submitting it in the form? furthermore what is the number `10` for?

Comment: The second parameter is called the "radix", basically which base to use. It's not required in modern browers, which always assume base 10, but in older browsers you can get unexpected results if you don't specify a radix. For example, numbers with a leading 0 could be parsed as octal (base 8). https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt

Comment: Using parseint works, however Is there a way to set the data type before submitting it to the database? I am using `<h3 style="margin-bottom: 0px;">Cookie Expiry</h3>
      <input style="width:100%" type="text" name="lu_ban_data[cExpiry]" value="<?php $cExpiry = get_option('lu_ban_data'); echo $cExpiry['cExpiry']; ?>" /></input>`

Comment: Since the value of `cExpiry` is an attribute of your input, it will always be read as a String in javascript. You could set it using a `data-` style attribute and retrieve it using jQuery's data() function, which will try to automatically cast the value for you. You can read more about that approach here: http://api.jquery.com/data/